# In Scala using an XML match expression I get the error: scala.MatchError. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, scala

I'm trying to acces specific information in an XML Document using Scala.

I set up this follwing example to show you my problem.

I create this XML "Document" it has the class scala.xml.Elem:

```
val testxml = <Object><Identity Type="Has a Type"/><Reality>"true"</Reality></Object>
```

I want to access the "Identity" attribute by using this match expression:

```
testxml match{

  case <Reality>{value}</Reality> => println("Congratulations the XML has a Reality!: $value ")

  case identity @ <Identity /> =>
    val typ = identity \ "@Type"
    println(s"Type is: $typ")
}
```

I tried to convert to string, nodeseq but it doesnt work. I expect to give me the output like "Congratulations....: true" 
                "Type is: Has a Type"

But I keep getting the error:

scala.MatchError:  (of class scala.xml.Elem)

What am I doing wrong?

Greetz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match` does not search recursively.

More like:

```
scala> testxml.child map { case <Reality>{ realities @ _* }</Reality> => realities
     | case id @ <Identity/> => id \ "@Type" }
res5: Seq[Seq[scala.xml.Node]] = ArrayBuffer(Has a Type, ArrayBuffer(&quot;true&quot;))
```

Edit:

```
scala> testxml.child flatMap { case <Reality>{ realities @ _* }</Reality> => realities case id @ <Identity/> => id \ "@Type" }
res2: Seq[scala.xml.Node] = ArrayBuffer(Has a Type, &quot;true&quot;)
```

Comment: Yes I get my values now returned as an ArrayBuffer. It is working. But how can I return the values of the buffer with the map expression?

Comment: That's a broad question. Maybe you mean we should have flattened.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a default match case to catch other matches:

```
case _ => println("Somethin else...")
```

Comment: Indeed this missed. But now I'm only getting my default match case.